# Unable to destruture values from object

Tags: javascript, object, next.js, destructuring

I am trying to destructure the data object using Next.js in client side

When I console.log(data) I get the below object

```
requestId: '1660672989767.IZxP9g', confidence: {…}, meta: {…}, visitorFound: true, visitorId: 'X9uY7PQTANO2a77GOGX6'}
confidence: {score: 0.9235436984457595}
meta: {version: 'v1.1.786+e63208b3'}
requestId: "1660672989767.IZxP9g"
visitorFound: true
visitorId: "X9uY7PQTANO2a77GOG
```

Then I try to extract visitorId like below

```
const {visitorId} = data;

console.log(visitorId)
```

When I console visitorID I get the below error

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'visitorId' of 'data' as it is undefined.
```

Comment: Can you share the exact content of the 'data' object?. In the example you have show it seems to be missing the opening and closing brackets, and missing the comma's separating the properties.

Comment: Please provide more code context.  How are you sending this request, are you waiting for the response to arrive?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: //the below worked for me by adding a ?

```
const visitorID = data?.visitorId;
```

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your code and it works fine.

Can you provide the code with the error?

```js
const data = {
    confidence: {score: 0.9235436984457595},
    meta: {version: 'v1.1.786+e63208b3'},
    requestId: "1660672989767.IZxP9g",
    visitorFound: true,
    visitorId: "X9uY7PQTANO2a77GOG",
};

const { visitorId } = data;

console.log(visitorId);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: I did it like this and worked.

visitorID = data?.visitorId;